# How to work with Ipad images? Xcode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview

I am creating an Ipad app and no matter what height I set my `ImageView` to be it is always too big.

For example I have an `ImageView` that's about 20 pixels tall and has all of the constraints that I need to keep it where I want it to be. When I play this 20 pixel tall `ImageView` on the Ipad simulator the `ImageView` covers about half of the Ipad screen.

How can I work with Ipad images if even a 1x1 pixel image view takes up a signifiant amount of the screen? (Yes, I made the 1x1 image just to see if it would still be insanely large)

Comment: we need to see some code or at least a screen shot

Comment: It all depends on the image view's constraints, the image itself, and the image view's content mode. But you didn't give any of that info, so it's impossible to help.

Comment: The constraints are set to 0 for the bottom, left, and right. With the top constraint being 150 to margin. The image itself is currently just the blank `ImageView` because I'm trying to figure out what size to create my image. I'm not sure what you mean by the "Content mode"

Answer (score 0):

Under Auto Layout, if you don't set the size of the image view absolutely, it will size itself to match the size of the image assigned to it. That is probably what is happening to you.